# Bicycle chainring dropping/ making a click sound. Help!

Tags: mountain-bike, bmx, sprocket, clicking, jumping

My bike is a bit dirty but can someone explain whats happening and a possible fix for this issue?

[a video with the issue on imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULxho.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange! You have a post that is on the same issue. Can you edit this post to include the photo from the other post? And can you explain what the issue is? Is it that the chainring is moving side to side? I can’t see clearly, and the video has no audio. Also, your other post says the chainring is broken, but the damage isn’t immediately obvious. Can you say *what* exactly is broken?

Comment: Also, I am editing the title. This looks like a chainring, which is connected to the cranks. Sprockets are the gears in back. Cogs is another word for sprockets.

Comment: I'm closing this as a dupe of the other one, because of the good answer already posted there.  Instead of splitting the resources available, we work to make the question and its answers as good as possible.   Don't take it personally, is just one of the ways we maintain high quality.