# How can I not break my sprocket next time

Tags: mountain-bike, bmx, sprocket

My sprocket was doing loud noises and when I looked at it, it looks like this
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iciYj.jpg

I bought a new sprocket but I want to know, what can I do to avoid these types of problems again?

Video of issue when installed on bike: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULxho.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bicycle sprocket dropping/ making a click sound. Help!](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/67988/bicycle-sprocket-dropping-making-a-click-sound-help)

Comment: @WeiwenNg I've voted to duplicate the _other_ way around, as Nathan has an answer here already that I think covers both quesitons

Answer (score 4):

It was set up without a spindle adapter. There can't be any wiggle between the sprocket and the spindle, or else something like this will happen.

[image]

Comment: Are spindle adapters sold as part of the chainring?  or are they a part of the crank?   Could OP use the original once a spindle adapter is fitted ?

Comment: Most BMX sprockets come with them to step down to whatever sizes they can fit. Sometimes, ie on less fancy ones, they're omitted and have to be obtained separate. BMX shops have them, as do the mail orders. If the center hole of this sprocket still fits the adapter snugly it would probably be fine, but not if it got mushed.